# in C++, how to make sure that one object is constructed before another object ?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

In C++, we have two global objects, both defined by others in different files. The construction of one object depends on the other already having been constructed.

```
class independent; 
class  dependent;
independent o1;
dependent o2;
```

In order to ensure o1 is constructed before o2, I can do it by declaring o1 before o2.

Can this assure that o1 is built before o2 ? What if compiler change the odering ?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html

Answer (score 8):

The C++ standard guarantees in order initialization of static variables within a same compilation unit, but the order is undefined in separate compilation units. This is often referred to as the *"static initialization order fiasco"*.

So if your variables are declared in the same .cpp, they're initialized in the order you declared them, and if they are in separate files, you just don't know at all (I've seen case of very aggressive linking optimizations that changed the ordering of static variables initialization regardless of the situation, but this is not standard compliant, and not supposed to happen in normal use cases).

## Core issue

Behind your question lies a **design problem**.

1. If one of your classes depends on another one, then its structure should show this dependency explicitly and make it impossible to get in a situation where the dependence is not fulfilled.
2. If you have one global object that depends on another one which you have no clear control over, then the dependent one probably shouldn't be a global.

Your question doesn't provide enough details to know what design is most suited to you, so here are a few suggestions from which you can make a decision.

### Dependency

So first, let's express this dependency...

#### Initialization time dependency

An instance of class `dependent` needs an object of `independent` for initialization, but doesn't need it anymore later on. Then just make the default constructor inaccessible and define your own constructor.

```
class dependent
{
  private:
    dependent(); // Implementation is optional

  public:
    dependent(const independent& sister)
    {
      // Initialize stuff
    }
}
```

#### Lifelong dependency

An instance of class `dependent` needs an object of `independent` during all its lifetime, and doesn't make sense otherwise. Then define a member that is a reference to the other object, and again, make the default constructor inaccessible and define your own constructor.

```
class dependent
{
  private:
    dependent(); // No implementation

  public:
    dependent(const independent& sister): m_sister(sister)
    {
      // Initialize stuff
    }

    const independent& GetSister() const { return m_sister; }
    void SetSister(const independent& sister) { m_sister = sister; }

  private:
    const independent& m_sister;
}
```

#### Lose dependency

An instance of class `dependent` may needs an object of `independent` to work, but still makes sense not to have one. Then define a member that is a pointer to the other object.

```
class dependent
{
  public:
    dependent()
    {
      // Initialize stuff
    }

    const independent* GetSister() const { return m_sister; }
    void SetSister(const independent* sister) { m_sister = sister; }

  private:
    const independent* m_sister;
}
```

### Initialization order

Now let's make sure the `independent` object is ready when the `dependent` one is.

#### Init function

You could use pointers and an `Init()` function.

```
Independent* sister = NULL;
Dependent* brother = NULL;

Init()
{
    assert(brother == NULL && sister == NULL);
    sister = new independent();
    brother = new dependent(sister);
}
```

#### Create on use

You could use static variables in functions to enforce the creation order. This works but makes it cumbersome to have several instances of the classes.

```
independent& GetSister()
{
    static independent sister; // Initialized on first use
    return sister;
}

dependent& GetBrother()
{
    static dependent brother(GetSister()); // Initialized on first use
    return brother;
}
```

#### No globals

Lastly, the cleanest approach is probably to try to get rid of global variables altogether. You would then use local variables instead (which you have perfect control over the creation order). Of course you would have to pass it through the functions that need them, and if there are a lot of them, it'd become cumbersome.

But then when you identify all the code the need these objects, it may make sense to move it within an object, and your two original global variables would simply become members of that object.

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo(): m_sister(...), m_brother(...)
    {
       // Initialize stuff
    }

    // Functions using the objects go here

  private:
    independent m_sister;
    dependent m_brother;
}
```

### Conclusion

Hmm, I realize my answer is long, I got a bit carried away. Here's the takeaway:

- Avoid global variables whenever you can.
- Express the dependency between classes.
- Don't hesitate to encapsulate code and state variables a class if makes things easier, it will make sense eventually.

Answer (score 8):

#### Simple: If `A` depends on `B` then *`A` should take `B` as a parameter in its constructors*.

[**Don't make your code lie to you.**](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)

Comment: This actually works both ways.  On one hand, it ensures "the code doesn't lie to you."  On the other hand, it intentionally leaks implementation.  For one layer, such as `CreditCard` and `CreditCardProcessor` it isn't so bad.  But when you start building layered software, you quickly start exposing state that doesn't need to be exposed.

As a specific example, I converted a "parameter in its constructor" pattern in one of the applications I work on into a singleton, and cut 7kB from the application's source.  That's a lot of "noise" removed from our code.

Comment: @CortAmmon: If there's nothing else I've learned from using C++, it's that one of its explicit ***non***-goals is reducing the amount of code in your code base. It's just not something you pursue in C++. Even the new features like `auto` aren't meant to save typing -- they're meant to make code generic. There are good and bad uses of features like `auto`, all of which reduce some kind of noise. Noise not what you want to measure by -- you want to measure by probability of failure. And failure probability isn't a function of signal-to-noise ratio, it's the other way around.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I suppose everyone develops for different companies with different results.  In some companies that noise actually is one of the leading causes of failure probability.  Noise forces you to either understand the code or make guesses as to what is noise and what is signal.  In my experience (which is related to a set of companies), it is easy to get a program large enough that it is virtually impossible to understand, so people guess constantly, and guess wrong.  In other circumstances, I suppose that may not ring so true.

Comment: As a pathological example of my point, I consider the specificity of `add(resultFactory, securityCtx, mathCtx, varA, varASecurityCtx, varAAtomicity, varB, varBSecurityCtx, varBAtomicity)` to not be worth the price of readability over its global using cousin `add(varA, varB)`, especially if the full version is available for those who actually need all those non-global contexts.

Comment: @Cort: I see what you're saying.... I think you can mitigate that problem by packaging all "context" parameters into a single object though.

Answer (score 6):

If two globals are in order **within a compilation unit**, then they will be initialized in order.  If they are in different orders in different compilation units (like they are in different .h files included in different orders by different .cpp), the result is undefined.

If you **must** have them in order, but you can't get them in the same compliation unit, consider using the singleton pattern.

```
class Independent
{
    public:
        static Independent& getO1()
        {
            static Independent o1;
            return o1;
        }
};

class Dependent
{
    public:
        static Dependent& getO2()
        {
            Independent::getO1(); // force o1 to exist first
            static Dependent o2;
            return o2;
        }
};
```

This uses the rule that static local variables are initialized when they are first used to ensure order regardless of how the .h files get included.

Comment: I think singletons are overkill here: a plain function returning a static instance would do.

Comment: @juanchopanza: singleton is actually a bad solution, since the question doesn't mention the uniqueness of the objects.

Comment: @JulienGuertault exactly. It is placing undue constraints on these types. But at the end of the day the real issue is that globals, be them singletons or not, should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @juanchopanza: If he simply moved the functions outside the class and didn't say the word "singleton" then it would be the same as most of the other answers here.  Look again, this code isn't _actually_ a singleton.  They're just globals, that use the "singleton" pattern to avoid issues.

Comment: @JulienGuertault This answer doesn't enforce uniqueness of the objects.  It's exactly the same as your "Create on use" pattern.

Comment: @MooingDuck: technically it does not, but in principle the singleton concept does, and in this answer in particular, placing the function inside the class puts a constraint within the definition of the objects. It is saying "Use these static functions and have only one instance, or do it yourself somewhere else".

Answer (score 2):

Use static function locals instead of globals.  Globals in a file are always initialized before any function is called, so one can use non-inline function calls to force the globals to be initialized in order.  This has the added benefit that you can freely and safely add more interdependent globals and it just magically works.

```
//header
class independent; 
independent& o1();
class dependent;
dependent& o2();

//cpp1 
independent& o1() {
   static independent o;
   return o;
}

//cpp2
dependent& o2() {
   o1(); //affirm that o1 is constructed first.
   static dependento; //now construct o2
   return o;
}

int main() {
    o1().thingy = -1;
    o2().thingy = 3;
}
```

Comment: "but they don't actually have to be defined in any cpp file" I'm not sure what you mean here. If you include the explicit specialization *definitions* in every TU, they violate the ODR. Otherwise, you'd need `extern` and put a definition in one specific TU. How do templates help here?

Comment: @DyP: The code in the question works in MSVC.  I don't recall why it works, but I think it had something to do with template static globals are allowed to violate ODR because no TU can possibly know what templates have been specialized in another TU or not, so it simply makes one for every TU (same with template function instantiations) and the linker merges them.  It's also _possible_ that I am showing the trick wrong, and the code in the question only works in MSVC.  But I'm pretty sure I recall something like this being standard.

Comment: @DyP: § 14.6.4.1/7  "A specialization for a... static
data member of a class template may have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a point of instantiation. A specialization for a class template has at most one point of instantiation within a translation unit. A specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation units."

Comment: Sorry, I was confused with the implication of an explicit specialization. It looks like a definition, but [temp.expl.spec]/13 says, "An explicit specialization of a static data member of a template is a definition if the declaration includes an initializer; otherwise, it is a declaration." (This means you don't need `extern` but the original comment should still be valid.)

Comment: Oh, but this means the definition is missing completely then :/ (clang++ also reports a linker error, undefined reference)

Comment: (I think the point of instantiation is only relevant for name lookup.)

Comment: If you want to investigate this behaviour with clang++, watch out because there's some diagnostic missing (a "bug"). [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ceb7a875a448652)

Comment: @DyP: I googled it and figured it out: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00aa8286f2203b4f.  I was doing an explicit specialization of the template in my static definition, and I didn't want to be doing that. (Also note that `globals_go_here` is an implementation detail and should not be in the user's code)

Comment: Yes, this is possible. However, I think you missed the important part: the dependency of `dependent` on `independent`. By using not fully specialized templates, I think the problem got worse [basic.start.init]/2 "Definitions of explicitly specialized class template static data members have ordered initialization. Other class template static data members (i.e., implicitly or explicitly instantiated specializations) have unordered initialization." (i.e. the order of init isn't even guaranteed in the same TU)

Answer (score 1):

If you have n globals, where n>0, the logical place for the construction is in the program unit containing main (). Instantiate them in the file in the order required.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee on the order of them being constructed.

Eliminating this dependency would be the best choice as well as trying not to use the globals. But if you must and if you want to make sure that one of the goes before another you better stick with the pointers and the functions returning the pointers.

```
independent * pindependent = null;
dependent * pdependent = null;

independent * getIndependent()
{
  if(pindependent == null)
    pindependent = new independent(); // fixed the bug pointed to by the Mooing Duck
  return pindependent;
}

dependent * getDependent()
{
  if(pdependent == null)
  {
    getIndependent();
    pdependent = new dependent(); // fixed the bug pointed to by the Mooing Duck
  }

  return pdependent;
}
```

In the header file you can expose the functions (optionally using extern):

```
extern independent * getIndependent();
extern dependent * getDependent();
```

Comment: @Mooing Duck: 1. This code displays the principle - it is not designed to work straight away. 2. Dynamic instantiation is not bad - in fact it is often good - it delays the initialization to the time it is needed and sometimes it never happens. 3. I find your comment is non-constructive and offensive, so stop mooing, please, and back up your words.

Comment: Well, my comment is missing, so I don't recall what I said, but I can see from your response that my post was offensive, and so I humbly apologize for whatever it was I said.  I was probably frustrated at the number of answers I disagreed with on this page and probably worded my response too strongly.

Comment: That being said, you should probably fix the bug so that it doesn't allocate a new object each and every time you call those functions and remove the memory leaks.  I still disagree with using dynamic memory to delay the construction until first use, there's easier ways to do it in this case.

Comment: Well, that's much better now. But you know what I think about Stack Overflow in general? There are many mean people here that jump to down-vote and criticize other's answers just because they (answers) have a flaw (or two) or reflect a different point of view. I don't really like it - it is not my idea of fun spending half an hour polishing a really simple code for no use. If somebody want a program written for them they should hire a developer, here we should throw in a rough solution, an idea, rather than full-fledged working implementation. Thank you for pointing to the bug.

Comment: @Sergey [I'm agree with you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330783/how-do-i-use-this-linked-list-implementation#comment26905463_18331188), but also note that we are humans, not a kind of Vulcan programmers :)

Answer (score 0):

Use global pointers and a function call to guarantee correct order:

```
//(!!PSEUDO-CODE!!)

Independent* o1;
Dependent* o2;

void CreateGlobalData();
void DestroyGlobalData();
//...    
void CreateGlobalData() {
    o1 = new Independent;
    o2 = new Dependent(*o1); //This is an assumption that the
                             //Dependent type takes an Independent parameter.
}
//...
void DestroyGlobalData() {
    delete o2;  //Always destroy in reverse order!
    delete o1;
}
```

Comment: There are easier ways

Comment: @MooingDuck How is a function call *not* easy?

Comment: How about, _not_ having a initialization function call, deinitialization, pointers, and new?  This way also requires a single function to know about all of the potential globals.